# How to NOT target any .NET Framework in Visual Studio 2010 for a C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Is it possible to create a new Win32 C++ project in VS2010 that wouldn't target a .NET Framework? Visual Studio seems to refuse to create a project unless at least one .NET Framework version is selected as a target. It also refuses to load a project if .NET is not installed on a computer, even if SLN / VCXPROJ files do not contain any .NET references. If .NET is not installed, Visual Studio still demands to select a .NET Framework version, but since no versions are available, it refuses to create a new project. But what if I want my application to have nothing to do with .NET and to run on a computer that doesn't have .NET installed? (The operating system I'm using is Windows XP, although that shouldn't make a difference).

I took the following steps:

1. Uninstall .NET.
2. In Visual Studio 2010, go to File -> New -> Project.
3. In the New Project window, under Installed Templates, click "Win32 Project -- Visual C++". At this point, Visual Studio begins to demand to choose a target .NET Framework version.

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible.  After all, Visual Studio has existed for Win32 development long before .NET was invented. Sounds like maybe you are creating the wrong project type to begin with.  Please [edit] your question to outline the exact steps you are taking.

Comment: Under `New Project` select `Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Project` (or something similar - I don't have 2010).

Comment: You may not have compiler support for native images installed.

Comment: @xcvbnm "*native images*" == *un*managed, no .NET. In the New Project dialog select Visual C++ under Installed Templates, then Win32, then Win32 Console App or Win32 Project. If you don't have/see any of those, modify the installation and add the missing pieces.

Comment: _"I probably don't have compiler support for native images installed, but it's irrelevant, because my application is not .NET. "_ It's not "irrelevant"; native images are exactly what you're trying to make.

Comment: @xcvbnm 1. I don't have a machine at hand without *any* .NET installed. That said, I never get prompted about .NET versions when creating an unmanaged C++ project, nor ever did. Could you post a screenshot of that particular dialog or prompt. 2. Then Win32 Project should be the right choice. 3. The linked page is about "*optimizing .NET Framework assemblies*", which doesn't apply when you build unmanaged C++ projects. In general, "native" means code compiled to native machine instructions, as opposed to "managed" which gets compiled to an intermediate language (in this case MSIL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*tl;dr*]   Visual Studio 2010 has the .NET Framework 4.0 as a prerequisite. The VS 2010 setup installs it if necessary, and the IDE will not function correctly if the .NET components are manually uninstalled afterwards. Unmanaged C++ applications can still be built outside the IDE without any .NET installed, and the resulting binaries have no runtime dependencies on .NET. Repairing the VS 2010 installation restores the .NET components, and gets the IDE to work as expected.

The following was tried on a clean XP SP3 (virtual) machine, with a fresh install of VS 2010.

- The setup lists .NET 4.0 as a prerequisite, and installs it if necessary.
  [image]
  [image]
- Manually uninstalling the .NET 4.0 components from Add Remove Programs breaks the IDE.
  [image]
- Repairing the installation gets the IDE working again. The New Project dialog has a top level .NET Framework version dropdown that defaults to .NET Framework 4, which applies to all project types. including the unmanaged C++ projects. However, the selection has no bearing on unmanaged projects, which do not target, use, or otherwise require .NET.
  [image]

Comment: Hope this helps, and it was too long for a comment, anyway. There must still be something different in your setup since you can get as far as the New Project dialog without any .NET installed, while VS wouldn't even start without it in my test install. But that's hard to track down without (a lot) more context.